# Combine two tables in Select (Microsoft SQL Server 2014)

Tags: join, sql-server-2014, subquery

I have two tables named `Publisher` and `Book`:

```
Publisher(
  PublisherID (PK),
  Name,
  Address
)

Book(
  BookID (PK),
  Name,
  Author,
  Price,
  PublisherID (FK on Publisher)
)
```

I want to display a **list of books published by Publisher named XXX**. How can I do that?

Comment: Sql joins can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Book.*
FROM
    Book
WHERE
    PublisherID = (
                    SELECT
                        PublisherID
                    FROM
                        Publisher
                    WHERE
                        Name = 'XXX'
                    LIMIT 1
                  )
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    Book.*
FROM
    Book
LEFT JOIN
    Publisher
ON
    Publisher.PublisherID = Book.PublisherID
WHERE
    Publisher.Name = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!